# TypeError: 0, _auth.updateProfile is not a function (it is undefined)

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase for authentication. there i want to update the user details i.e displayName using updateProfile method but it is not working. all the tutorials or example online which i have tried are i think outdated or may be i am making some mistake. i am using the latest versions of all (i.e. React Native, Firebase/auth)

this is my code snippet where i am trying to update the user profile.

```
const createAccount = async event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    try {
      if (
        firstName === '' ||
        lastName === '' ||
        email === '' ||
        password === '' ||
        confirmPassword === ''
      ) {
        Alert.alert('All Fields must be Filled');
      } else if (password !== confirmPassword) {
        Alert.alert('Your Password and Confirm Password Does Not Match');
      } else if (password.length < 6) {
        Alert.alert('Password must have at Least 6 Characters');
      } else {
        const userCredentials = await auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email,
          password,
        );
        const user = userCredentials.user;
        // await console.log(user, email, password);
        if (user) {
          updateProfile(auth.currentUser, {
            displayName: `${firstName} ${lastName}`,
            firstName: firstName,
            lastName: lastName,
          }).then(() => console.log(user));
        }

        if (user) {
          navigation.navigate('Login');
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      Alert.alert('Error', e.message);
    }
  };
```

kindly guide me through this as this is my first time using firebase authentications